# Detect programmatically, if the System lock can be disable or not in Android?

Tags: android

There are a few apps out there installing which the user is unable to remove his system-security. Eg.. When user installs outlook configured with exchange, he is prompted to set a PIN/Password , and after that the NONE and SLIDER option is Grayed out in the system security page.

Can I programmatically detect whether the NONE or slider is Grayed out or not for a given device ?